# Django - Conflicting models in application, same path but different case

Tags: python, django

Django 1.8.
I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/home/rentapplication/django-rentapplication/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
[35mrentapp    | [0m    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
[35mrentapp    | [0m    utility.execute()
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
[35mrentapp    | [0m    django.setup()
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[35mrentapp    | [0m    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[35mrentapp    | [0m    app_config.import_models(all_models)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
[35mrentapp    | [0m    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[35mrentapp    | [0m    __import__(name)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/home/rentapplication/django-rentapplication/accounts/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[35mrentapp    | [0m    from .landlord import Landlord
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/home/rentapplication/django-rentapplication/accounts/models/landlord.py", line 20, in <module>
[35mrentapp    | [0m    from accounting.models import Account
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/home/rentapplication/django-rentapplication/accounting/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[35mrentapp    | [0m    from .transaction import Transaction, RequestedWithdrawal
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/home/rentapplication/django-rentapplication/accounting/models/transaction.py", line 16, in <module>
[35mrentapp    | [0m    class Transaction(TimeStampedModel):
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 309, in __new__
[35mrentapp    | [0m    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
[35mrentapp    | [0m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 221, in register_model
[35mrentapp    | [0m    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
[35mrentapp    | [0mRuntimeError: Conflicting 'transaction' models in application 'accounting': <class 'accounting.models.Transaction.Transaction'> and <class 'accounting.models.transaction.Transaction'>.
```

My structure is following:

```
accounting
  api
  migrations
  models
    __init__.py
    account.py
    transaction.py
```

In **init** i have following code:

```
from .account import Account
from .transaction import Transaction, RequestedWithdrawal
```

I have no idea from where django came up with upper cases transaction package, I didn't use it anywhere in my code. 
So why I'm having this error, and how to solve it?

UPDATE.
account.py imports

```
import StringIO
import csv
import logging
from decimal import Decimal

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel
from notifications import notify

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from accounting.tasks import notify_of_withdrawal_request_action
```

landlord.py imports

```
import datetime
import logging
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import Counter
import random
import string
import analytics

from django.utils.timezone import utc
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.db import models, transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel
from easy_thumbnails.fields import ThumbnailerImageField
from jsonfield import JSONField
import stripe
from rentapplication.utils import generate_random_slug
from applications.models import ApplicationTemplate
from accounting.models import Account
from reports.models import  Report, ReportSourceProfile, ReportSource
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.conf import settings
import base64
```

transaction.py imports

```
import logging
from decimal import Decimal


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from django.db import models
from django_fsm import FSMField, transition
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

from reports.models import Report

import stripe
```

Comment: Im not using __init__ method for models, im using __init__ file for models package to split up models into different files, dont see anything against it in docs, if u do - please provide a link. The problem that there different cases for my model pathes, and it cause a erorr, while i certainly have only one path.

Comment: Can you add your imports from `landlord.py`, `account.py` and `transation.py`

Comment: Yes, i have added imports

Comment: Can you try removing any *.pyc files in the source tree, in case there's one left over from a previously existing .py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why i was seeing this strange error message and stack trace. But the problem was with circular import inside models.py and tasks.py.