# Django: conflicting models in (third-party) application

Tags: django, task-queue, django-q

I integrated a third party app into my Django project, and only when I import it will I get this error message.

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'task' models in application 'django_q': <class 'django_q.models.Task'> and <class 'models.Task'>.
```

I'm puzzled because my app runs well withouth it so I wonder how it could be an error on my side. I'm only using the app in its most simple use case. My general question is then: how can I investigate ?

So the app is [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io), a task queue ([github](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/releases)). I installed it and called it in its most simple usage, following the good documentation.

```
CACHE = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache_table',
    }
}

Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'DjangORM_queue',
    'workers': 4,
    'timeout': 3600,
    'retry': 4000,
    # 'queue_limit': 50,
    # 'bulk': 10,
    'orm': 'default'
}
```

api.py:

```
# api.py
# not putting all imports or __init__.py
def myhook(task):
    print task.result
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

def mymethod(request, pk, **kwargs):
    from django_q.tasks import async, result
    async('models.MyModel.method', pk, hook='myhook', sync=True)
```

Now `manage.py runserver` is ok, until I call my api and it reaches `tasks.async`. Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[...]/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/.../my-project/searchapp/models/api.py", line 965, in mymethod
    tasks.async('models.MyModel.mymethod', pk, hook='myhook', sync=True)
  File "/home/[...]/django_q/tasks.py", line 43, in async
    return _sync(pack)
  File "/home/[...]/django_q/tasks.py", line 176, in _sync
    cluster.worker(task_queue, result_queue, Value('f', -1))
  File "/home/[...]/django_q/cluster.py", line 369, in worker
    m = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/[...]/django_q/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Task(models.Model):
  File "/home/[...]/django/db/models/base.py", line 309, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/home/[...]/django/apps/registry.py", line 221, in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'task' models in application 'django_q': <class 'django_q.models.Task'> and <class 'models.Task'>.
```

I first checked I don't have a model named Task, nor do my django installed apps. We don't.

I searched for a similar pb and found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591399/django-1-7-conflicting-models), so I tried to tweak the imports of django-q, with no success (it doesn't mean I did it right though).

Is it a circular import ([SO hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35975817/1506338)) ?

A Django bug report (which wasn't) is interesting also, I found [comment 13](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22280#comment:13) particarly (about double entries in sys.path and ways of import). My `sys.path` has `[ my_project, …/site_packages/django_q, …/site_packages/]` so I don't feel impacted by comment 13's description;

I couldn't reproduce the issue on a fresh django project;

I feel like trying another queuing system :/ 
Any hints on what could be wrong ?

Thanks !

*ps: I could also point to my full repo*

Comment: Try searching your whole `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` dir, or wherever you have all your python packages installed, for a file containing a string `class Task(`, I bet there is something there.

Comment: Indeed there was, my venv was dirty. I removed two packages that I don't use, I temporalilly renamed `fabric`'s class, I deleted the `*pyc` and retried, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, I went with [huey](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html). It's simple and complete.

[django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) looks like a good solution too, with a django dashboard integration.